Error handling of Maui Community Toolkit CameraView
How is it possible to handle errors when using e.g. Maui Community Toolkit CameraView?
In one example it throws CommunityToolkit.Maui.Core.CameraException and crashes the app. How can this handled?
Code is simply from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/views/camera-view?tabs=android
<toolkit:CameraView />
Thanks.

Use basic C# exception handling

But where? In the code behind?

Add the platform you are testing on: Android/IOS/Windows/MAC. Each platform requires you to take specific actions to implement the camera. Besides the exception type, you should put exception message. Also "one example" means nothing to me. Add the specific code that is causing the crash.

I have updated question with code ref.

I have switched to Maui.Camera instead, so nvm. Thank you anyway.
